# Problem with related greatest common divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $d = \gcd(a,b)$. Then $a=kd$ and $b=xd$ where $x$ and $k$ are integers. Prove that $\gcd(x,k) = 1$ (that is, that $x$ and $k$ are relative prime numbers or coprime numebers). Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the fact about the GCD which says it can be written as a linear combination of the arguments. That is $ \gcd(a, b) = at + bs $ for some integers $t$ and $s$. Substitute for $a$ and $b$ and then make use of the definition that $ x , k $ are relatively prime if and only if $\gcd(x , k) = 1$

Comment: Thank you so much !! I just didn´t realized that GCD could be written as a linear combination !!

Comment: No worries. Not a difficult result to understand. Comes with the existence proof for the GCD. Good reference would be David Burton's Elementary Number Theory.

Answer (score 4):

Try proof by contradiction. What would happen if $\gcd(x,k)>1$? Would $d$ still be the *greatest* common divisor of $a$ and $b$?